# Value Error: Item not in List when it clearly is

Tags: python, string, list, indexing

I have a list, `abbreviations`, filled with string objects. I am trying to call the `.index` of a string in my list. When I call the `.index` method with a string I get a ValueError: 'LING' is not in list, when it clearly is in the list.

[image]

My code:

```
for item in abbreviations:
    print item

print abbreviations.index("LING")
```

Why does 'LING' not exist when it clearing does? I have added my following lines of code, which searches 'abbreviations' for the index of a string. I am baffled -- "LING" is clearly in my abbreviations list.

EDIT (Additional Code):

```
import csv 

myfile = open("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/classAbrevs.csv", "rU")

lines = [tuple(row) for row in csv.reader(myfile)]

longSubjectNames = [] 
abbreviations = [] 

masterAbrevs = []
for item in lines:
    longSubjectNames.append(item[0])
    abbreviations.append(item[1])

with open ("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/masterClassList.txt", "r") as myfile:
    masterSchedule = tuple(open("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/masterClassList.txt", 'r'))

for masterline in masterSchedule:
    masterline.strip()
    masterSplitLine = masterline.split("|")

    subjectAbrev = ""
    if masterSplitLine[0] != "STATUS":
        subjectAbrev = ''.join([i for i in masterSplitLine[2] if not i.isdigit()])
        masterAbrevs.append(subjectAbrev)

finalAbrevs = []
for subject in masterAbrevs:
    if (subject[-1] == 'W') and (subject[-2:] != 'UW'): 
        subject = subject[:-1]
    finalAbrevs.append(subject)

x = 0

for item in abbreviations:
    print item

print abbreviations.index("LING")

for item in finalAbrevs:
    if masterSplitLine[0] != "STATUS":
        concat = abbreviations.index(str(finalAbrevs[x]).strip())
        print "The abbreviation for " + str(item) + " is: " + longSubjectNames[concat]
    x = x + 1
```

The output of:

```html
masterAbrevs = []
for item in lines:
    longSubjectNames.append(item[0])
    abbreviations.append(item[1])

print '-'.join(abbreviations)
```

is:

```html
ACA-ACCY-AFST-AMST-ANAT-ANTH-APSC-ARAB-AH-FA-ASTR-BIOC-BISC-BME-BMSC-BIOS-BADM-CHEM-CHIN-CE-CLAS-CCAS-COMM-CSCI-CFA-CNSL-CPED-DNSC-EALL-ECON-EDUC-ECE-EHS-ENGL-EAP-EMSE-ENRP-EPID-EXSC-FILM-FINA-FORS-FREN-GEOG-GEOL-GER-GREK-HCS-HSCI-HLWL-HSML-HEBR-HIST-HOMP-HONR-HDEV-HOL-HSSJ-ISTM-IDIS-IAD-INTD-IAFF-IBUS-ITAL-JAPN-JSTD-KOR-LATN-LAW-LSPA-LING -MGT-MKTG-MBAD-MATH-MAE-MED-MICR-MMED-MSTD-MUS-NSC-ORSC-PSTD-PERS-PHAR-PHIL-PT-PA-PHYS-PMGT-PPSY-PSC-PORT-PSMB-PSYD-PSYC-PUBH-PPPA-REL-SEAS-SMPA-SLAV-SOC-SPAN-SPED-SPHR-STAT-SMPP-SUST-TRDA-TSTD-TURK-UW-WLP-WSTU
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/sortClasses.py", line 25, in <module>
    with open ("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/masterClassList.txt", "r") as anything:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/masterClassList.txt'
```

Comment: Did you check for leading/trailing spaces? Examine the actual value, not how it looks like when printed. Use `repr()` instead if you must.

Comment: No it is giving correct output on my machine, are you sure that you have initialized the list ? or may be you have used the `index` variable somewhere in the code which has overridden the property, Kindly paste the whole code snippet ?

Comment: Now your codes clearly changed. You must be more spesific in your question.I am pretty sure you doing something wrong somewhere in your codes, otherwise this is a really low chance to be a bug like this.

Comment: I have added all my code above. Essentially my code compiles a list of abbreviations from a master .txt. It then searches my "abbreviations" list for a string and then prints the matching index from my third list.

Comment: `with open ("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/masterClassList.txt", "r") as myfile:
    masterSchedule = tuple(open("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/masterClassList.txt", 'r'))` well this seems clearly wrong

Comment: Nowhere -- where should I be closing it?

Comment: @PhilipMcQuitty, can you show the result of this line: `print '-'.join(abbreviations)` after the for/loop of `for item in lines:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, from the result you ran:

**"LING\t"** is shown in your list, not **"LING"**

with running this I get the desired index:

```
abbreviations.index("LING\t")

71
```

To correct this, there are many methods to strip the **\t**, I'm showing one of those:

```
abbreviations.append(item[1].strip())
```

By correcting this line, your **item[1]** will strip the **\t** before appending to your **abbreviations** list.

Comment: Does the strip function not strip the /t ?

Comment: @PhilipMcQuitty, **strip()** should take out the **\t** however I can't see you implement this in your code, let me update my answer to ensure you know what to do

Answer (score 1):

```
myfile = open("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/classAbrevs.csv", "rU")

lines = [tuple(row) for row in csv.reader(myfile)]

longSubjectNames = [] 
abbreviations = [] 

masterAbrevs = []
for item in lines:
    longSubjectNames.append(item[0])
    abbreviations.append(item[1])

with open ("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/masterClassList.txt", "r") as myfile:
```

The problem is here;

```
with open ("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/masterClassList.txt", "r") as myfile:
```

You defined `myfile` **before** here,

```
myfile = open("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/classAbrevs.csv", "rU")
```

So actually `abbreviations = []` is not taking data from `classAbrevs.csv`.Because it's taking data from `masterClassList.txt` as you defined `myfile` with this line;

```
with open ("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/masterClassList.txt", "r") as myfile
```

That's why your string not in that list.Also this line;

```
for item in lines:
    longSubjectNames.append(item[0])
    abbreviations.append(item[1])
```

Are you sure is `item[1]` has all of the strings that you want?

> And I tried these codes I just copy-pasted it from your's and here is the result;

[image]

Comment: So I changed: "with open ("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/masterClassList.txt", "r") as myfile:" to with open ("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/masterClassList.txt", "r") as anything:" and am still getting the same error.

Comment: @NoMorePuppies, although what you suggested is indeed a bug from OP, that doesn't affect **abbreviations** list as **item[1]** should have already appended. It has nothing to do with **myfile** being assigned to something else.

Comment: @NoMorePuppies yes I am certain that item[1] has all the strings I need in it.